# I have image path into media library, how I can show it into cshtml?

Tags: media-library

My model contains string property **ImagePath** with media file path, for example:

```
"/sitecore/media library/Comp_Images/Division1/Client1/Client_Images/BobRoss.jpg"
```

How can I display it into cshtml in sitecore rendering ?
something like:

```
 <img  src="@Model.ImagePath" />
```

Thank you

UPDATE:

1. model is coming from database  - ImagePath field type is string
2. images are being uploaded
   programmaticaly via API from another app.

Comment: Where does your model get this path from? What type of field do you have in your Sitecore template for this (assume it is `Image`)

Comment: Also have you looked at Glass Mapper? http://glass.lu/ this makes this kind of thing a lot easier, more testable and has experience editor support built in.

Comment: Since you have the full path, you can use the `GetItem()` method to get the item. Cast it as mediaItem. Example: `var imageItem = (MediaItem)Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("path of item here");`. Once you have the item, you can use the GetMediaUrl() to generate the image url. Then you store it in your property `ImagePath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have the media path in Sitecore, you can use the `GetItem()` method to retrieve the item.

Below is the code snippet you can use to get the url of the media and assign it to your property `ImagePath`

```
var imageItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("path of item here");
this.ImagePath = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageItem);
```